# Change text of Button, after some, time when you click on it, in Android

Tags: android, button

I want to change the text of button after some seconds, say 5 seconds.

Suppose at the starting you have one button on an activity, having text "?",
when you click on this button it should take ay number from a range suppose 0-10,
after showing one number as a text on a button it should again change to "?" after 5 seconds.

I have tried Thread.sleep() but it didn't work.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use:

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View view)
    {
        btn.setText(""+i);
        Handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                 btn.setText("?");
            }
        }, 5000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I have implemented the same thing and it is working fine.

Comment: If your problem solved, accept answer, this would help you getting answers quickly in future.

Answer (score 0):

// declaration at class level

Timer timer = null;

```
Handler handler=new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) 
    {
                // update UI here i.e. set The value on Text View

    }
};
```

// call the startTheTask Method from Activity, it will initiate a timer which will work   after every 5 seconds

void startTheTask() 
{

```
         if(timer != null)
          {
         timer.cancel();
     timer = new Timer();
     TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask()
     {
         public void run()
         {
                       // your random number code generation here
                      // to update UI call
                       handler.sendMessage(handler.obtainMessage());
         }
     };
     timer.schedule(timerTask, 5000);
          }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working Button derivative.

```
package com.anonymous.sample;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class AutoChangeButton extends Button {
    private static final int DEFAULT_DELAY = 1000;

    private Runnable backToQuestionMark = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            setText("?");
        }
    };

    private void initButton() {
        setText("?");

        this.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                setText("foo~~");
                postDelayed(backToQuestionMark, DEFAULT_DELAY);
            }
        });
    }

    public AutoChangeButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        initButton();
    }

    public AutoChangeButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initButton();
    }

    public AutoChangeButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
        initButton();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the timer when click on button and change the button text like the following code below:

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View view)
    {
        button.setText(sometext);
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                button.setText(text);
            }
        }, 0, 3000); 
    }
}
```